# Download mobile app screen content as image

Tags: ionic2

We are trying to save the contents of a mobile app (using ionic2) as an image and the same would be downloaded when user clicks the url for downloading the same.

In page.ts

```
declare var window;
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-hospital',
  templateUrl: 'hospital.html',
})
export class HospitalPage {

  pdfObj=null;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public platform: Platform,public file: File,public fileOpener: FileOpener ) {
  }
  downloadPDF(){

          //code to be inserted to save the whole page content as image and to be downloaded to mobile      }
```

the related HTML is as:-

```
<button type="button" (click)="downloadPDF()">Download PDF</button>
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [print](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp), or the [screenshot plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screenshot/) ?

Here is a small snippet, it's a bit hacky but it will give you an idea of what you can do.
The snippet won't work in this page to avoid XSS security issues, but it will work in your project.

```js
var printPage = function() {
 var a = document.getElementById('myContentStyle').value;
 var b = document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML;

        window.frames["print_frame"].document.title = "My document";
 window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = '<style>' + a + '</style>' + b;
 window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
 window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
}
```

```css
#myContentStyle, #printFrame {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myContentStyle">
  @page {}
  .page-break {page-break-after: always;}
</div>

<button onclick="printPage()">Print!</button>

<div id="myContent">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <h1 class="page-break">Test 2</h1>
</div>

<iframe id="printFrame" name="print_frame" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Comment: I tried both and in either cases it captures only the visible section of the app not the whole content...Any suggestions.(Need to capture the whole content of the page /screen)

Comment: What do you mean by the whole content ?

Comment: There is content which is only viewed when scrolled just like in web page.the mobile screen has long content and needs to be scrolled down to view the whole content.

Comment: Print should do the job then, as it can print a whole DOM element of your choice

Comment: I edited my answer with an example. The snippet won't work in this page for security reasons but it will work in your project.